# Publish website File System Without cs Files VS 2012

Tags: publish

I'm trying to publish a website using vs 2012 but I'm getting the the aspx files and the cs files, I just want to publish the necesary files (aspx without cs).

Something different I see is that I can't select other configuration like Release, I mean the 'combobox Configuration' only has Debug configuration in the list items. Maybe that coulb be part of my problme.

The situation is that if I use this publish (with cs) when I run the website in the target server it says the .cs file is missing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the dummy cuestion. I see what I was missing. I need to check Precompile during publishing option.

Thanks anyway